# Is it possible to classify "branches" in the MWI of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations

In Everett's Many Worlds Interpretation of QM, what would be classified as a "world" or a "branch"?

Would the "reality" of what I'm consciously experiencing be distinguishable from a separate "branch" or "reality"? For example, would a "world" in which "I" am an evil mastermind be distinguishable from the "world" I am experiencing right now?

What are the Criteria for such a classification?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104253/discussion-on-question-by-quantumexplorer-is-it-possible-to-classify-branches).

Answer (score 1):

No observer can identify a world he is not a part of. By your choice you are either an evil mastermind or a quantum explorer.

You could produce 10 clones of yourself (or do it as a thought experiment). Put them in a room together and all clones are in the same world. Cause them never to meet and each clone will be in a different world from their own perspective. If you told one of them that it has 9 other versions it might think how it can contact them but without you (as the link, in the same world) it would have no way of doing so (without the knowledge).

I suppose one could still say two clones might meet by chance. If they both had encountered mirrors they might recognize they are clones. I think in that case you would say two branches connected.

You have some life experience though and you probably know what pain is. You might think you could allow one clone to become an evil mastermind (and endure eventual punishment by authorities) because it is not you but when you think the clone would feel exactly what you feel if you were in the situation you might not allow them to do that. You would try to determine an outcome.

Nature has laws which produce results. This question was asked from two different accounts by the same person. As you can see these two "branches" are only one because you have only one world actually.

Comment: I don’t feel like this answer really addresses the question. Im just wondering if it’s possible to distinguish a branch, and how you would do that.

Comment: @QuantumExplorer - Sorry about that. The reality of what you are consciously experiencing is bound by your local physical realm. It is a small and personal reality. One might say that many worlds in the Universe are already distinguishable from yours since you will never have any connection with them.